# How do you cancel a scene transition animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-design-library

I'm starting an activity with a scene transition using a shared element like so:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 
    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, mImageView, "image_view_transition").toBundle());
```

And I'm specifying `android:transitionName="image_view_transition"` for the ImageView in `SecondActivity`'s layout, so the scene transition animation is played out nicely to and from the started activity, without me needing to do anything else.

Although, in some circumstances, I don't want to play the reverse scene transition from `SecondActivity` back to the starting Activity. How do I cancel this animation from within `SecondActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

In `SecondActivity` you can register a callback for your shared elements and cancel it if desired:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onMapSharedElements()");
                    if (shouldCancelWindowTransitionOnExit) {
                        sharedElements.put("image_view_transition", null); // This will reject the transition
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setEnterSharedElementCallback(android.app.SharedElementCallback)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SharedElementCallback.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Handler().postDelayed(runnable,3000)
}

private val runnable:Runnable= Runnable (){
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        imgLogo?.transitionName = null
    }
}
```

the above code work for me

Answer (score -1):

Try calling this after you call finish() in your second `Activity`.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_change, R.anim.no_change);
```

With no_change animation being:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Reverse animation is still being played.

Comment: Could you not set a new null transition or a blank one with:

`getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(transition);`

Comment: I've tried all transition setting methods on the `Window` object, both in the starting Activity and in the finishing Activity, in all sorts of combinations, and none of them take effect.